# Determine minimum number of moves to reach top left corner of 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm working through some leetcode problems and came across this one:

I'm given a 2-D array, for example:

```
given[][] = { {1, 6, 2},
              {1, 6, 4},
              {1, 9, 2} }
```

Each cell in the array represents the number of moves I must make from that cell. I can move only up or only left each time I stop on a cell. I want to find the minimum number of moves necessary to go from the bottom right of the array to the top left cell.

For example, in the given array, I should return 2, going from `given[2][2]` to `given[0][2]` to `given[0][0]` as this is the shortest possible path. If there is no possible way to get to the top left, I should return -1.

I'm not sure where to even begin. Can anyone offer any pointers? I was thinking I could represent this as a graph and apply Djikstra's Algorithm, but I don't know if this is a viable solution.

Comment: Do, just a BFS starting from bottom right. Check always for boundaries and make sure you don't double visit by keeping track of visited cells. The first you land on `0, 0` will be the shortest path

Comment: Also, I'm curious. Care to link?

Comment: If you can move _only_ up or left, does that mean that there are only two possible correct traversals here (of lengths 2 and 3)?

Comment: @user1984 a friend of mine sent me this problem and asked me to look at it--i'm not sure from where it came :(

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes there is a valid traversal of length 3 but since there's also one of length 2, I just return that since it's less.

Comment: I'd do a stack-based DFS, aborting each path if it runs out of bounds. At each choice you only have to try "up" and "left" paths. (You can also abort if any path is longer than a known shorter path.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- when doing DFS the first solution isn't necessarily optimal. You have to check other path deep enough to go over the current solution.

Comment: @user1984 It's not, but it's simpler to write as a first attempt.

Comment: yes, you're probably right. I just wanted to make sure they don't take the first solution as this may not be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all the elements are positive numbers.

```
static int minMoves(int[][] given, int x, int y, int count) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        return count;
    int step = given[x][y];
    return Math.min(minMoves(given, x - step, y, count + 1),
        minMoves(given, x, y - step, count + 1));
}

static int minMoves(int[][] given) {
    int count = minMoves(given, given.length - 1, given[0].length - 1, 0);
    return count == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] given = {{1, 6, 2}, {1, 6, 4}, {1, 9, 2}};
    int result = minMoves(given);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
2
```